# what is the purpose for EXOPlayer's MergingMediaPeriod & SingleSampleMediaPeriod?

Tags: multimedia, exoplayer

Dears:

I found there are two classes named **"SingleSampleMediaPeriod"** & **"MergingMediaPeriod"** which implements the interface = **MediaPeriod**.

But I do NOT see where they are applied?

Does there anyone know the usage case for them?

Thanks~